# Webpages do not load properly and skip some content

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, internet

When I run a speed test I get pretty good stats. Even the webpages open quickly but they open so fast that they skip some content when I use Google Chrome or Firefox. If I reload the webpage it works, any suggestions?

Comment: Is it for all websites or just specific ones? Try flushing your DNS cache history by opening CMD and typing **ipconfig /flushdns**

Comment: I have tried dns flush and updating my graphic drivers,adobe flash player.Problem remains same.

Comment: try pressing Ctrl + F5

Comment: @Bilo I apologize but i am not asking about how to reload webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps until it works:

1. Disable all extension.
2. Update Flash Player or Shockwave Player.
3. If all else fails, do a complete uninstall and reinstall.
4. Try to access the site from another PC.

If problem still exist, then it is the site's problem.

Comment: It is simpler to just run the browser in "safe mode". In Firefox that is in the menu Help (press alt-h to open it) / Restart with Add-ons Disabled...